# How to use deep copy with parameter

Tags: reactjs

I've asked about this question a while ago and I have faced a problem.
What I want to try to do is

add `{ label: "", data: "", background: "" }` into `datasets` and then I want to update the elements.

So I got the answer that i should use deep copy and i used it like this:

```js
const addAxis = index => {
    setDataContext(dataContext =>
      dataContext.map((data, idx) => {
        return idx === index
          ? {
              ...data,
              datasets: [
                ...data.datasets,
                { label: "", data: "", background: "" },
              ],
            }
          : data;
      })
    );
  };
```

but the thing is that i passed `addAxis` function through props like this:
`addAxis={addAxis(1)}` to add in each `datasets` in `DataContext[index]` :

## DataContext

```js
 const [DataContext, setDataContext] = useState([
    {
      labels: defaultLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "dataSetting",
          data: defaultDatas,
          backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      labels: defaultLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "dataSetting",
          data: defaultDatas,
          backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      labels: defaultLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "dataSetting",
          data: defaultDatas,
          backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
        },
      ],
    }, 
    {
      labels: defaultLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "dataSetting",
          data: defaultDatas,
          backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      labels: defaultLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "dataSetting",
          data: defaultDatas,
          backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
        },
      ],
    }, 
    {
      labels: defaultLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "dataSetting",
          data: defaultDatas,
          backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
        },
      ],
    },   {
      labels: defaultLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "dataSetting",
          data: defaultDatas,
          backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      labels: defaultLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "dataSetting",
          data: defaultDatas,
          backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
        },
      ],
    }, 
    {
      labels: defaultLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "dataSetting",
          data: defaultDatas,
          backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
```

but i got `Maximum update depth exceeded` error so i tried to change `addAxis={addAxis(1)}` to  `addAxis={() => addAxis(1)}`  like this but it's not working and I've tried to find to fix it but i have no idea what I'm wrong.
Thank you in advance.

## Edit

This is where i pass addAxis  :

```js
 const layout = [
    <DataSide id="first" key="1233" onClick={chartItself}>
      <SettingMenu
      index={1}
        show={show[0]}
        chart={chart[0]}
        chartData={DataContext[1]}
        addAxis={addAxis}   ///this is addAxis
        deleteAxis={() => deleteAxis(1)}
        changeTitle={changeTitle(1)}
        changeLabel={changeLabel(1)}
        changeYaxis={changeYaxis(1)}
        changeXaxis={changeXaxis(1)}
        changeLayout={changeLayout}
      />
      {firstDataType.map(
        (id, index) => chart[0].key === id.key && firstDataType[index]
      )}
    </DataSide>,
    <DataSide id="second" key="1234" onClick={chartItself}>
      <SettingMenu
        show={show[1]}
        chart={chart[1]}
        chartData={DataContext[2]}
        addAxis={() => addAxis(2)}
        deleteAxis={() => deleteAxis(2)}
        changeTitle={changeTitle(2)}
        changeLabel={changeLabel(2)}
        changeYaxis={changeYaxis(2)}
        changeXaxis={changeXaxis(2)}
        changeLayout={changeLayout}
      />
      {secondDataType.map(
        (id, index) => chart[1].key === id.key && secondDataType[index]
      )}
    </DataSide>,
    .....
    ..
```

### SettingMenu

```js
 <Link
            to={{
              pathname: `/csvFile/${chart.key}`,
              state: {
                index:index,
                chartData: chartData,
                plugins_title: plugins_title,
                changeLayout: changeLayout,
              },
              data: {
                addAxis: addAxis,
                changeTitle: changeTitle,
                deleteAxis: deleteAxis,
                changeLabel: changeLabel,
                changeYaxis: changeYaxis,
                changeXaxis: changeXaxis,
              },
            }}
          >
```

## This is where i use addAxis as a child component

```js
  <AddBtn>
        {ChartName === "Bar" && (
          <>
            <button onClick={addAxis(index)}>Add Bar </button>
            {Axis.length > 0 && <button onClick={deletebtn}>Delete Bar</button>}
          </>...
```

Comment: Can you show us where and how do you pass the props `addAxis`

Comment: Thank you so much Sir ! Im middle of something so I'm going to answer it later !! So appreciate !!!

Comment: No problem, it is not necessary if your problem is solved :D

Comment: I just edited the question . I really appreciate you to answer it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [mock use case with codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-currying-nqo9j?file=/src/App.js). You can check the code. Click on the button to add an element to the dataset of that particular element.

Basically, what you can do is, pass the props as `addAxis={addAxis}`, and call the `addAxis` function in the child like:

```
onClick={() => addAxis(/* args */)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! you really helped me a lot !! I solved the problem !!